# Why am I getting the error "Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'NSMutableArray *' from 'NSArray *'." while sorting keys?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray, nsmutabledictionary

With the code below I am getting the error, "Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'NSMutableArray *' from 'NSArray *'." I am not using an NSArray, why am I getting this error and how can I fix it?

```
(NSMutableArray) = [NSMutableDictionary keysSortedByValueUsingComparator: ^(id obj1, id obj2) {

    if ([obj1 integerValue] > [obj2 integerValue]) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
    }

    if ([obj1 integerValue] < [obj2 integerValue]) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
    }
    return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
}];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the method `keysSortedByValueUsingComparator:` returns a pointer to a sorted `NSArray` containing the keys. You are taking that `NSArray` pointer and trying to assign it to an `NSMutableArray`. pointer This is an error because `NSArray` is the superclass of `NSMutableArray` and does not respond to all of the same selectors/methods.

You need to assign the output of `keysSortedByValueUsingComparator:` to an `NSArray` pointer instead of an `NSMutableArray` pointer.